# How to register a callback in ConTeXt

Tags: context, lua

In ConTeXt mkiv, how do I register a callback? `callback.register()` does nothing (and IIRC most callbacks are frozen anyway) and somewhere I found `tasks.appendaction`, but this gives me an error that `tasks` is not defined (nil).

I'd like to add something to the `post_linebreak_filter` callback.

---

Edit: thanks to Khaled's answer and help from the Mailing list, I've got a solution now. The key is to create my own namespace:

```
moduledata.mystuff={}
```

and add my function:

```
moduledata.mystuff.show_hyph = show_hyph
```

and to register the function to the "finalizers" callbacks, which are the `post_linebreak_filter` equivalent in ConTeXt.

```
nodes.tasks.appendaction("finalizers","after","moduledata.mystuff.show_hyph")
```

See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11960/how-to-register-a-callback-in-context#12052) for a complete example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `nodes.tasks.appendaction()`, I don't know the official way to use it, but after trial and error (and grepping through the source), I came up with:

```
bidi.handle_bidi = nodes.installattributehandler {
    name      = "bidi",
    namespace = bidi,
    processor = bidi.ctxprocess,
}
nodes.tasks.appendaction("processors", "characters",  "bidi.handle_bidi")
```

and:

```
nodes.tasks.enableaction("processors", "bidi.handle_bidi")
nodes.tasks.disableaction("processors", "bidi.handle_bidi")
```

(copied from my [`bidi`](https://github.com/khaledhosny/luadirections/blob/master/t-bidi.tex) module, and this is equivalent to `pre_linepreak_filter`)

Better ask Hans for a definite answer.

Comment: I have asked on the NTG ConTeXt list, waiting for an answer.

Comment: I've got a reply from Hans, I'll post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have taken the [example from the LuaTeX wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Show_the_hyphenation_points) and transformed it into ConTeXt code with the help of Khaled and Hans:

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\de
\startluacode
moduledata.mystuff={}
show_hyph = function(head)
  while head do
    if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then -- % hlist, vlist
      show_hyph(head.list)               -- % head.head in LuaTeX > 0.65
    elseif head.id == 7 then             -- % disc
      local n = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      n.mode = 0
      n.data = "q 0.3 w 0 2 m 0 7 l S Q"
      n.next = head.next
      n.prev = head
      head.next = n
      head = n
    end
  head = head.next
  end
  return true
end

moduledata.mystuff.show_hyph = show_hyph

nodes.tasks.appendaction("finalizers","after","moduledata.mystuff.show_hyph")
\stopluacode

\starttext
Seit zwei Jahren...
\stoptext
```

The "finalizer" is the ConTeXt equivalent of the `post_linebreak_filter` callback.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry for entering this discussion late. (I can't quite follow since parts are already deleted.) Just wanted to say: I usually _strongly_ discourage people to include answers into the question. Just a pointer is OK, but I think we should keep answers to answers. What do you think? (@Patrick: In my opinion you've already got to much of an answer in the question now.)

Comment: @Hendrik: Putting a summary at the end of questions  is fairly well established on SO when there are several useful answers.  E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c   Maybe this should be a meta qn?

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the feedback. Well, for a question with _three hundred and two_ answers, a summary is somewhat necessary, but here we have _two_ answers. But still it might be worth asking for other opinions on meta.